# 2 drop down boxes with 2 submit buttons, which one was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 drop down boxes with the same name with 2 submit buttons (for each)

One appears at the top of the page and the other appears at the bottom. Both have the same function ("Cancel" or "Update" records in my grid)

I have this code:

```
$(div).on('click', '.action-submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var action = $(".action-input");
```

However when I do a:

```
if (action.val() == "")
```

And one of the drop downs aren't selected, it fails the check. Both have to be selected.

How can I determine which drop down box is being worked with? Or am I forced to give them separate names and check for both everytime?

Comment: please share jsfiddle

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your question correctly, you should be able to just use `e.target`.

Sample implementation is as follows:
[**Sample Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9L4nH/)

JS:

```
$('div').on('click', function(e) {
    $(e.target).css('background', 'yellow');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>One div</div>
<div>Another div</div>
```

Comment: If you had kept the delegate event handling from OP you could just use `$(this)`, much easier.

Comment: Personally I think it's unnecessary, the event already holds the required info anyway.

Comment: True, but in that line of thought, jQuery is also unnecessary.

Comment: Not necessarily, for example the target <div>-s may be created dynamically in which case using `.on()` is a lot more straight-forward. But we're just splitting hairs here now.

Comment: `.on()` doesn't magically work with dynamically created elements; it's just a glorified `addEventListener()` after all.

Comment: click happens on a submit button within the div. click event cant be attached to the button as its dynamically generated. when submit button is clicked, it checks .action-input if it has a value. if the action has a value, it continues, otherwise it raises an error. I have 2 of the same submit buttons/input values (one at the top of the page, one at the bottom). When the bottom one is used without the top one containing a value, an error is raised. it should only fire for that specific set of buttons, but I don't want to necessarily have to change their functionality as they're the same thing

Comment: if you look at the code I posted, you will see that the click happens on the button and nowhere else within the div, however the button(s) are exclusively IN the div and the event shouldn't fire for anything outside the div (in case another developer uses the same name for their buttons)

Answer (score 3):

```
var action = $(this);
```

This way you check what have you clicked.